# ng-click is not working child elements

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I very new Angular js Can any one help me.

My HTML code is:

```
<th>
    <a class="tooltips" href="">
        Click
        <span>
            <font data-ng-click="click1();">All</font>
            <font data-ng-click="click2();">UnAll </font>
        </span>
    </a>
</th>
```

My CSS is:

```
a:focus.tooltips span {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:.8;
    top:26px;
    left:100%;
    margin-left:-65px;
    z-index:999
}
```

My script is:

```
$scope.click1 = function() {
    alert("click1");
};
$scope.click2 = function() {
    alert("click2");
};
```

My problem is ng-click events not fired can any one please help me

Comment: No errors getting @K.Toress

Comment: `clcik2` vs `click2` ?? Also show controller scope in markup. If the methods are being called outside of controller they won't work

Comment: click2 only @charlietfl in my controller i wrote correct spelling

Comment: please Provide complete htmlcode.. Here $scope is undefined

Comment: @user3263194: what i posted that is the html code only.

Comment: Why $scope is undefined, can please tell me the reason @user3263194

Comment: Where is your controller defined?

Comment: I defined controller... @user3263194

Comment: Are you using it inside a form?

Comment: NO I am not using form @Hareesh

Comment: Not sure it's related, but try not to have `href=""`. Use `href="javascript:void(0);"` instead.

Comment: No it is not working @OmriAharon

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you have declared the **controller directive** in your HTML template as following :

index.html :

```
<html>
<body ng-app="mymodule" >
<a class="tooltips" href="" 
    data-ng-controller="clickController"> 
    Click 
    <span>
        <font data-ng-click="click1();">All</font>
        <font data-ng-click="click2();">UnAll </font>
    </span>
</a>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, make sure you have declared correctly **your controller in a angular module and injected the $scope** as following :

app.js :

```
var myModule = angular.module('mymodule',[]);

myModule.controller('clickController',['$scope', clickController]);

function clickController($scope){

    $scope.click1 = function () {
        alert("click1");
    };

    $scope.click2 = function () {
        alert("click2");
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rémi Becheras, I am using same thing.. but when i clicking on span element from css I wrote "a:focus.tooltips span" i mentioned above code. when it will active that time All and UnAll will showing i am trying to fire events but it is not firing

Comment: CSS rules don't matter against angular ng-click directives or controller workflow. Forget it for now, and make your angular code working. Then, work with your css.

Comment: what you written same thing i tried but it is not working @ Rémi Becheras

Comment: did you included angularjs script (before your app.js script) ?

Comment: and the `ng-app="mymodule"` directive for example in your body tag as in my code ?

Comment: Yes everything is working fine. Only this events are not fired

Comment: Is there any way to stop parent event click, when try to click the child element? @Rémi Becheras

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example code.

There is two way to write your links.

Please note that Angular is an HTML5 javascript framework and that the `<font></font>` tag is deprecated in HTML5 and maybe before.

The first way is preferable, and the ng-click is on the  tag. Its not required but preferable in this type of case were you have a `<a>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-app="mymodule" >


<div ng-controller="clickController">       
    <a class="tooltips" href=""         
        data-ng-click="click1()"
        > 
        <span>
            <font>
                Click all 
            </font>         
        </span>
    </a>
    <br>
    <a class="tooltips" href="" 
        data-ng-click="click2()"
        >
        <span>          
            <font>
                Click UnAll 
            </font>
        </span>
    </a>    
</div>

<br><br>
-----------------
<br><br>

<a class="tooltips" href="" 
    data-ng-controller="clickController"> 
    Click 
    <span>
        <font data-ng-click="click1();">All</font>
        <font data-ng-click="click2();">UnAll </font>
    </span>
</a>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var myModule = angular.module('mymodule',[]);

    myModule.controller('clickController',['$scope', clickController]);

    function clickController($scope){

        $scope.click1 = function () {
            alert("click1");
        };

        $scope.click2 = function () {
            alert("click2");
        };
    }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```